# E: Unable to locate package juju-core

Tags: juju, cloud

I am following https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started but when I run first command in this guide ubuntu give me following error.

```
superc@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install juju-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package juju-core
superc@ubuntu:~$
```

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS in my VMPlayer. Can anyone help me please.

Thanks

Comment: On that very link it gives you further steps to take if it complains about not finding the package (you have to add the PPA mentioned there to your repository list, using the commands they give you). Try those instructions first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started) you may want to try to add the ppa first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install juju-core
```

Comment: Hello Pierre,

I used the following command before add the ppa

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

juju installed on my machine.
Thanks